# How get the auto increment column name from the table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I tried this query:

```
 SELECT 
    IDENT_SEED('{0}'), IDENT_INCR ('{0}'), IDENT_CURRENT('{0}') AS Identity_Seed 
 FROM 
    information_schema.COLUMNS 
 WHERE 
    table_name = '{0}' AND column_name = '{1}'
```

`name[i]` is the table name, `dt.Columns[j].ColumnName` is the column name, but it working for every column and not only the specific the identity one

Maybe someone know how I can in that query:

```
SELECT 
   IDENT_SEED('{0}'), IDENT_INCR ('{0}'), IDENT_CURRENT('{0}') AS Identity_Seed ", 
   name[i]
```

add into the select the column name???

I just need to get the column name or add expression that where the column name (to get only one option)

Comment: Please learn to use parameterized queries.

Comment: ok srry >< you mean in code One?

Comment: I mean in all of it. You should be using parameter names (e.g. `@tableName`, `@columnName` instead of `'{0}'` and `'{1}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
    name
FROM 
    sys.identity_columns
```

That will output all tables (in `schema.table` format) and the identity column (if any) for that table.

**Update:** OK, so you obviously want to do this for a single table - OK then use **this** code:

```
string sqlStmt = "SELECT name FROM sys.identity_columns " +
                 "WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(your-connection-string-here))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (sqlStmt, conn))
{
     // add table name as parameter
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = name[i];

     // open, execute, close
     conn.Open();

     object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     conn.Close();

     // if result is NULL --> no identity column
     if (result != null) 
     {
          string identityColumn = result.ToString();
     }
}
```

That will return the name of the `IDENTITY` column for the table with name `name[i]` - or it will return `NULL` if that table doesn't have an `IDENTITY` column ....

Comment: The object's id - any SQL Server object has a unique `id` value. It's present in almost all the system catalog views. Here, it's the **table** object's `id`

Comment: wont work for me, it put error:

"SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME('{0}') + '.' + OBJECT_NAME('{0}'),  name FROM sys.identity_columns",name[i]"

Comment: @AsafShazar: ***what*** error? Also: what **version** of SQL Server are you using? This works in **2005** and newer....

Comment: i work with the sql server 2005 with c#

already try that:
sql1 = string.Format("SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U')) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U')),  name FROM sys.identity_columns", name[i]);

Comment: Please use parameterized queries in your examples.